# Product of matrices with only one nonzero entry on each column

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a full-rank $n \times m$ rectangular matrix with entries in a DVR, with $n \leq m$ (less rows than columns) and we may assume $n < m$ if useful. Is there an $m \times m$ invertible matrix $A$ in the same field such that $RA$ has at most one nonzero element on each column?

Note that this is like asking for (little less than) half of the conclusion of Smith Normal Form with (little more than) half of the assumptions.

Comment: For those wondering like I was, DVR = [discrete valuation ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring)

Comment: If $p$ is a uniformizer, how do you propose to column-reduce $\begin{bmatrix} p & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @math54321 you multiply on the right by $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ -p & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Do you want the entries of A to be in the same "DVR"? In the question you have written "same field".

Comment: The product isn't satisfactory: $\begin{bmatrix} p & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ -p & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2p & -p \\ -p & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Even if you meant $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -p & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, neither of these are invertible (having nonunit determinant $-p$)

Comment: Anyways, if $\begin{bmatrix} p & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is diagonal, then $pb + d = c = 0$, so $\det \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = -abp$ which is never a unit

Comment: @math54321 ok but it need not be diagonal, it may be that one of the rows is made of 0s.

Comment: If you had a row of 0s then the determinant would be 0, but the determinant of the original matrix is $p$